# RDC - MS Access to SQL Server - Different users different speed

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, remote-desktop

I am hoping someone can help as my knowledge on this is limited.

A client currently has an Access database we designed connected to their SQL Server. When running the database on the same local network it runs fine.

When running the database on an RDC the speeds varies from one office to another. Clicking on a button to open up a form can go from 1-2 seconds to 10+ seconds.
They have 3 remote desktop servers in same location as the SQL server all on the same local network.

I don't believe they have an issue running any other applications on the RDC as the same server is being used by Sage. It is just this access database connecting to the SQL server.

I am trying to understand how the speed can vary so much and determine if it is the Access database or something else to do with the Remote Desktop servers.

I understand it might be a hard question to answer as there are a lot of variables but any thoughts or advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are all the servers the same spec and work under the same type of workload and the same Ethernet speed and connectivity? Are they all under the same domain? Is there a difference in speed when working on the servers from their local console as opposed to an actual remote login?

Comment: Usually the speed of the RDP connection makes little difference. I would try remote into the TS server on the local high speed office LAN and try the application. Since the RDP connection is only sending the screen and mouse clicks, then a wide variation in the RDP speed has LITTLE effect on the  performance of the Application. In other words, if the application is slow, then it something in regards to how the application is running on the RDP server - not the RDP connection speed.